# Best structure for buffer

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, buffer, complexity-theory

I'm implementing a buffer but I'm not sure which structure I should use.

I was thinking either a LinkedList or, even if I don't need to store any value, an HashMap (but I could simply put a null value).

As maximum efficiency I was thinking to use the HashMap since that the complexity of `containsKey` is **O(1)**.

Instead the complexity of `LinkedList.contains` is **O(N)**.

But, still, I'm not sure if I should discard the LinkedList or any other structure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Buffer should be as fast as possible, so I would use an `array` (as most alghoritms use), which complexity **O(1)** is the best you can get. Other structures need to call methods (extra time), moreover `hashmap`, even with **O(1)** access, can be **extremely slow**, when `put` and `remove` methods are called frequently due of **hash collisions**.

Comment: But I need to remove elements randomly. Using an array, I would need to iterate on the array any single time in order to find the element that I want to remove.

Comment: You can do this: put object into the array, attach used index to the object. When it comes to remove, you just use attached index to find it's position in array.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. Of course by removing you mean to set the cell = null, right? Because otherwise on every remove I would need to create a new array and copy the remnant elements into it.

Comment: Of course, otherwise it wouldn't be buffer - buffer is always fixed sized. Note, that hashmap is also fixed size structure (objects are stored into the array of fixed size, where index is (hashcode mod array.length) of the object), but it can expand it's size when there is no space i. e. it creates new underlying array with double size and rehashes objects into the new one.

Comment: If you need to iterate over an array you just have to skip null positions. Hope it helps.

Comment: Which is basically what I need to do in case there is no space anymore. I mean, to create a new array with double size and to copy the objects.

Comment: Then it depends on your needs, but from my point of view, array wrapper as I described can do the same thing but faster - no hash collisions, no hash computation: available array indices would be in some linkedlist so finding empty index would be just matter of availableIndices.poll(). In short, If you do not care about "super efficiency", use hashmap.